# Refresh data in ListView flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation

I have a menu page which has tabA and tabB. The appBar has a search button.

**menu.dart**

```
   @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Item List'),
        actions: [
          _currentIndex == 0
              ? Row(
                  children: [
                    IconButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.pushNamed(context, SearchScreen.ROUTE,
                                arguments: list);                        
                        },
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.search,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        )),
                    IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(
                        Icons.tune,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                            ...
                            }
                          }
                        });
                      },
                    )
                  ],
                )
              : Container()
        ],
        bottom: TabBar(
          unselectedLabelColor: Colors.white,
          labelColor: Colors.white,
          isScrollable: false,
          tabs: <Widget>[
            Tab(
              text: "Tab A",
            ),
            Tab(
              text: "Tab B",
            ),
          ],
          controller: _tabController,
          indicatorColor: Colors.white,
          indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
        ),
        bottomOpacity: 1,
      ),
      body: TabBarView(
        controller: _tabController,
        children: <Widget>[
          ShowTabA(),
          ShowTabB()
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In tabA, it has a listView. When I tap on one of the listview item, it will navigate to EditPage. When return from EditPage, I will refresh the data in tabA. All the list item will be updated.

**tabA.page**

```
initState(){
    _bloc.getItemList();
}

Navigator.pushNamed(EditPage.ROUTE,context).then((onValue){
 _bloc.getItemList();
});
```

---

My problem here:

When I click the search icon in menu page , it will navigate to SearchScreen page.Once user click the list item in SearchScreen, it will navigate to EditPage.

When back from EditPage, I want the list in TabA page refreshed but it can't because I navigate using `pushReplacementNamed` in menu page . How to achieve that ?

**SearchScreen.dart**

```
Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context);
```

Comment: are you using a provider in your app to manage the state? I guess _bloc is the object of that provider. If my guess is right then you can use StreamProvider or ChangeNotifierProvider to update your list automatically as soon as your list value changes.

Comment: @CodeRunner But the problem now is `_bloc.getItemList();` not getting called once it back from EditPage.

Comment: Navigator.pushNamed(EditPage.ROUTE,context).then((onValue){
 _bloc.getItemList();
}); this part won't be called when you come back from that page because you are calling that while you are going to edit page not coming back from edit page. you can call getItems()  while you hit save or update button on edit page or what you can do that is  you can call getItems() inside of dispose method of that page so it will call the method every time you come back from editPage.

Comment: where should I put the dispose method? In tab A?

Comment: nope in your edit page

Comment: @CodeRunner when back from EditPage, the list still not updating

Comment: @Tony Why you need pushReplacement?

Comment: @MidhunMP because when back from edit page, I want it displays tabA instead of searchPage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated answer on Modified Question:**

Since you are using pushReplacement your await won't work. You can use the following approach to make it work:

First you have to define your routes:

```dart
routes: <String, WidgetBuilder> {
   '/': (BuildContext context) => // Your MainPage,
   '/menu': (BuildContext context) => MenuPage(),
   '/search': (BuildContext context) => SearchPage(),
   '/edit': (BuildContext context) => EditPage(),
}
```

Navigation from Menu to Search:

```dart
void goToSearch() async {

   await Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/search", arguments: list);
   _bloc.getItemList().then((onValue){
      setState(() {
         list = onValue;
      });
   });

}
```

Use *pushNamed* instead of *pushReplacementNamed* when navigating from Search to Edit:

```dart
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/edit");
```

**Important step** When you have to go back to Menu from Edit, you've to use [popUntil](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/popUntil.html) method:

```dart
Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName('/menu'));
```

Comment: Sorry, I think my question is unclear and misleading.I have updated it.

Comment: Please help T.T

Comment: @Tony Happy to know that it helped. Happy Coding!!!